# Too many languages in solr config

Tags: solr, typo3

We have a solr configuration based on apache solr 8.52.
We use the installation from the TYPO3 extension ext:solr 10.0.3.

In this way we have multiple (39) languages and multiple cores.
As we do not need most of the languages (for sure we need one, maybe two further) I tried to remove most of them with deleting (moving to another folder) all the configurations I identified as other languages, leaving only these folders and files in the solr folders:

```
server/
  +-solr/
  | +-configsets/
  | | +-ext_solr_10_0_0/
  | |   +-conf/
  | |   | +-english/
  | |   | +-_schema_analysis_stopwords_english.json
  | |   | +-admin-extra.html
  | |   | :
  | |   | +-solrconfig.xml
  | |   +-typo3lib
  | |     +-solr-typo3-plugin-4.0.0.jar
  | +cores/
  | | +-english/
  | |   +-core.properties
  | +-data/
  | | +-english/
  : :   :
```

I thought that after restarting the server it would only present one language and one core. This was correct.
But on start it noted all the other languages as missing like:

```
core_es: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core core_es: Error loading schema resource spanish/schema.xml
```

Where does solr get this information about all these languages I don't need?
How can I avoid this long list of warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it does not hurt to have those cores. As long as they are empty and not loaded, they do not take much RAM and CPU.

But if you still want to get rid of them, you need to do it correctly. If you just move core's data directory, this does not mean it is deleted because solr server also needs to adjust config files. Best way is to use curl like this:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=UNLOAD&core=core_en&deleteInstanceDir=true'
```

That would remove the core and all its data.

Comment: as english should stay but a long list of others should go I used: `for lang in bg <insert long list> zh ; do curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=UNLOAD&core=core_$lang&deleteInstanceDir=true"; done`